# Multi-dimensional array decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

My question is about decomposing a muti-dimensional array into a product of matricies.  To ask the question I will work towards the tensor, and then ask the question about the reverse process.

Let $s_{i}$ be a 2D vector, and consider $K_{ij} = s_i s_j$.  Next, take the matrix $K$ and multiply it by a constant factor, $\beta$, $\beta K$.  Now preform the following:
$$
W_{ij} =\exp (-\beta K_{ij})
$$
by which I mean *exponentiate each term individually, not matrix exponentiation.*  Next preform a singular value decomposistion on $W$,
$$
W_{ij} = U_{ia}\lambda_{ab}V_{bj}^{\dagger}
$$
and define the following quantity: $Q_{ij} \equiv U_{ia}\sqrt{\lambda_{aj}}$.  Using $Q$ we build the final multi-dimensional array:
$$
T_{ijkl} = \sum_{a}Q_{ai}Q_{aj}Q_{ak}Q_{al}
$$
*Now suppose I am given an array with the exact same size and symmetries as $T$, is it possible to recover $Q$?*

I attempted to contract two $T$s as
$$
A_{ij} \equiv T_{iabc}T_{jabc} = \sum_{\alpha\beta}Q_{\alpha i}Q_{\beta j}(Q_{\alpha a}Q_{\beta a}Q_{\alpha b}Q_{\beta b}Q_{\alpha c}Q_{\beta c})
$$
and try to pull $Q$ out using whatever orthogonality arguments I can come up with, but so far have been unsuccessful.  Thank you.